# В PHP 7 отсутствует curl_dll

Tags: php

Работаю на Apache2, Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 7. В php.ini включил extension=php_curl.dll. При запуске php пишет

```
    Unable to load dynamic library /usr/lib/20151012/php_curl.dll No such file in directory
```

Пробовал установить php-curl - не помогло.
Установка php7.0-curl - пишет что такого пакета не существует.
Как мне в итоге подключить php-curl ?

Comment: Потому, что не надо использовать Windows бибилотеки под убунтой

Answer (score 3):

Молодой человек вы работаете в Linux/Unix там DLL файлов в природе нет ( это виндовое расширение) вам нужен файл php_curl.so (тоже самое что и dll только для Linux/Unix) Если вы сделали

> apt-get install php7.0-curl

ТО в php.ini php_curl.so добавится автоматически ( если нет надо добавить вручную) а строчку с *php_curl.dll* вам нужно закаментировать... поставив перед ней **;**